# scale_fill_identity and row order

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to maintain row order when using `scale_fill_identity`? The colours in the code below don't match up to the colours in the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("x1", "x1", "x1", 
                       "x2", "x2", "x2", 
                       "x3", "x3", "x3"),
                fill = c("red", "blue", "green", 
                         "green", "red", "green",
                         "blue", "red", "blue"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = 1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = fill), stat = 'identity', colour = 'black') +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

The colours in the output get grouped together in alphabetical order (blue is always at the top of the graph, then green, then red), rather than the colours being in the same row order as they are in `df`:

[image: Incorrect colour orders in bars 2 & 3]

Here's how I'm trying to make it look:

[image: correct order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit weird, but you can just call out the colour vector without aes

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = 1)) + 
geom_bar(fill=df$fill,stat="identity",col="black")+
scale_fill_identity()
```

Thanks to @cholland, you don't need the scale_fill_identity in fact, since no legends required:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = 1)) + 
    geom_bar(fill=df$fill,stat="identity",col="black")
```

Comment: Following your idea the line `scale_fill_identiy()` can be omitted

Comment: This does the trick, thanks! Can you explain why it works please? I've always thought that you should never use `$` inside any of the ggplot calls

Comment: So when you set the fill inside geom_bar, if you don't provide aes, you can specify it by say fill="blue", which gives you all blue, or you provide a vector of colors that are as long as the value you are going to plot, in this case, it's df$fill

Comment: Ideally you don't use $, because you are always passing the dataframe df to the geom_bar() function, calling $ is quite redundant, and confusing. And you don't get a legend if you do this. But if you need to specify the color explicitly, this is the easiest way